# Не могу отловить ошибку python3

Tags: python, обработка-ошибок

Проверяю ip-камеры на доступность с помощью python и opencv. Хочу чтобы просто вывело true или false

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(data['rtsp'])
print(vcap.isOpened())
```

однако если камера не доступна появляется ошибка

```
[tcp @ 0x7f2430003f00] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
```

Что мне сделать чтобы обработать ее?

Comment: try-except, так же как и любую другую ошибку в питоне

Comment: не понятно что после exсept должно пойти

Comment: Ну например `print(False)`?

Comment: Я имею в виду что это за ошибка т.е. except что_тут :

Comment: Для того, чтобы просто отловить исключение, не вываливаясь из выполнения кода, достаточно просто указать except: - это сработает на любом исключении. А вообще, нужно смотреть код ошибки. что-то типа except cv.error as e: (или except cv2.error as e:) - тут уж нужно читать документацию по OpenCV